# Transform any directed graph to tree?

Tags: graphs

Is there any algorithm which can transform any graph to tree, with providing mapping from one to another?
Suppose we have directed graph:

```
E->A
A->C
C->C
C->B
B->A
B->D
```

I want to convert it to tree in such way, that all biggest cycles is converted to node, and all dependencies out of this cycle is binded to this node. So, in other words, all cycles represented as nodes.

For example, the biggest cycle here:

```
A B C
```

Biggest cycle is a cycle which do not contained in other cycles. So, in example [C] is one-node-cycle but it contained in bigger cycle [A,B,C], so it is not biggest. On the other hand [A,B,C] is not contained in any other cycle, so it is biggest. Graph can contain multiple biggest cycles.

Output will be:

```
E->F
F->D

where F is alias for A,B,C
```

Is there some algorithm for this?

Other interesting example with 2 biggest cycles:

```
A->B
B->A

A->C

C->D
D->C
```

Will be converted to:

```
E->F
where E is alias for A,B
where F is alias for C,D
```

Comment: This is likely very difficult, since finding out whether there is a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete.

Comment: You should formally define what you mean by "biggest cycles".

Comment: Is a Hamiltonian cycle a "biggest cycle"?

Comment: I may not understand the question, but is there a chance you are looking for the block-cut tree? That is the "biggest cycles" are the biconnected components.

Comment: Well, Im not sure it is Hamiltonian cycle, because sub-cycle can also be Hamiltonian.

Comment: @marcv81 Wow, block-cut tree might be interesing idea, but blocks in this case are sets of verticies, not set of edges.

Comment: That's one way to look at it. You can also say a vertex replaces all the edges which form a group of cycles :) This said I now understand better and I don't think that's what you're looking for.